# MQL4 EA ignoring some arrows

Tags: mql4

I have created a simple EA in mql4 that execute trades based on the appearing of some BUY and SELL arrows. However the EA ignores some of the arrows. I need help.

I want the EA to trade based on all arrows that appears. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

The codes below.

```
void OnTick()
{  
   int total_orders = OrdersTotal();
   int buy_ticket = 0;
   int sell_ticket = 0;

   // Reading Indicator buffer
   double super_buy_arrow  = iCustom(NULL,0,"super-arrow-indicator",0,0);
   double super_sell_arrow = iCustom(NULL,0,"super-arrow-indicator",1,0);


   // Buy or Sell if Arrow appears
   if(total_orders == 0)
   {
      if(  super_buy_arrow != EMPTY_VALUE )
      {
           buy_ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, FixedLot, Ask, Slippage, Ask-150*_Point, Ask+250*_Point,NULL, Magic, 0, Green); 
      }
      if(  super_sell_arrow != EMPTY_VALUE )
      {
           sell_ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_SELL, FixedLot, Bid, Slippage, Bid+150*_Point, Bid-250*_Point,NULL, Magic, 0, Red);
      }
   }

   }
}
```

Comment: it is possible that your indicator is repainting, in such case there's no way to catch an arrow (or other indicator sign) because it does not exist when it is called

Comment: Well, my indicator is a non-repainting indicator. It's stuck ones it appears. I've using it for over a year now.

Comment: alternative might be that the indicator recomputes the last closed bar, if a new bar appears (so either current, or last+current once per bar). in that case, arrow may appear on the closed candle, but you do not check for that

Comment: anyway, there is no problem in the code, of course if you do not miss important parameters. the problem is probably with the indicator

Comment: ok, Thank you very much Daniel Kniaz.